# Permanent magnet with residual magnetization and Induced EMF

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

Let's consider a permanent magnet and a coil. No current flows through the coil. Can the permanent magnet induce an EMF into the coil (and thus an induced current)? Why? 
Many thanks.

Comment: Hint: A changing magnetic field induces an electric field.

Comment: @sbp Yes, for sure. But why can a magnet with remanent magnetization considered as a changing magnetic field? Magnetization is a property of a 'magnetized' ferromagnetic material related to the magnetic field measured inside the material... what could I misunderstand? Thanks!

Comment: Okay. It's not about a ferromagnetic material having a changing magnetic field. The field is constant for such a material. Say I fix the loop. Now I bring in the magnet from far away. So for the loop there was initially no $B$, but as I bring the magnet closer there is a changing $B$ that the loop feels, there is a change in flux, and thus current flows in the loop. Infact the current flows in such a direction so as the abhor this change in $B$. This is called Lenzs Law. Look up Griffiths.

Comment: @sbp Ok, if some movements are allowed, everything is clear. But in a device like this one https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/369212/inductive-sensor-how-does-it-work, where permanent magnet and coil are attatched, I have to conclude that the current induced by the permanent magnet was induced at the beginning of the assembly process.. Is it correct? Thanks again!

Comment: See the point is that $\textbf{B}$ should change with time to induce $\textbf{E}$ and viceversa.

Comment: @sbp Am I misunderstanding that at the beginning of the assembly process, when the coil become near the permenent magnet, the flux passing through the coil changes during time? The induced current could be induced in that moment... Do you think, instead, that I should ignore the initial assembly process and, at assembly completed, focus on the more relevant flux variation due to the magnetization of the thoothed (moving) wheel?

Answer (score 1):

A permanent magnet will only induce a current if it in motion relative to the coil.

Comment: Ok, but in this case the coil and the permanent magnet are attatched... I think that the explanation is in the condition "permanent magnet with remanent magnetization"

Comment: If the coil and permanent magnet are attached I see no way in which a current could be induced, the motion has to be relative.

Comment: current can be induced if u change the reluctance, by inserting  a ferromagnetic core in the coil for ex